# htaccess file coversion from localhost to server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created my .htaccess file for working in localhost. It works as expected. But when I deploy it on the server it starts causing 500 internal error.

**Question**:
How to convert this htaccess file from localhost to server?

My htaccess file for localhost is this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /htmlpattern/

RewriteRule ^public\/$ public/index.php?category=none [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public\/(#[a-zA-z]+)$ public/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public\/([a-zA-z-]+)$ public/index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [NC,L]
```

Basically on localhost i am using xampp.Path is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\htmlpattern
```

htaccess file is placed in the htmlpattern folder.

On server I am using cpanel which has a directory structure of

```
/home/faazjama/public_html/
```

All of my files are in the public_html folder.

Basically the problem is that I have no idea whether I have to rerwrite a rule
with someting like ^http://example.com/$ or it should be like
^/home/faazjama/public_html/$.

Any help would be very much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the. htaccess to capture the path of the server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I am using cpanel. If i want to redirect my website home page to anywhere  else what should I write

Comment: http://freevects.com needs to go to the public_html/index.php?category=none. Please if you could write that rule for me. Thanks